# AddPrivateFont to App Title / Title bar in WxPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, wxpython, wxwidgets

My problem is I can't find the way to use `AddPrivateFont` to change  the App Title font in WxPython.

From the demo
https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/AddPrivateFont.py

and the sample
https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20add%20a%20menu%20bar%20in%20the%20title%20bar%20%28Phoenix%29

I tried

```
        f = wx.Font(
            pointSize=18,
            family=wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
            style=wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
            weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL,
            underline=False,
            faceName="Youth Touch",
            encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT,
        )

        xwq = self.SetAppName("Custom Gui 1")
        xwq.SetFont(f)
```

But I'm getting the error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetFont'`

I also tested the same with `SetTitle`

```
        f = wx.Font(
            pointSize=18,
            family=wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
            style=wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
            weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL,
            underline=False,
            faceName="Youth Touch",
            encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT,
        )

        frame.SetTitle('yourtitle')
        frame.SetFont(f)
```

and the same error shows up.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid

import os
import sys

try:
    gFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except:
    gFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
gDataDir = os.path.join(gFileDir, "myfonts")


filename = os.path.join(gDataDir, "YouthTouchDemoRegular-4VwY.ttf")
wx.Font.AddPrivateFont(filename)


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(800, 600))

        f = wx.Font(
            pointSize=12,
            family=wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
            style=wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
            weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL,
            underline=False,
            faceName="Youth Touch DEMO Regular",
            encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT,
        )
        title.SetFont(f)

        self.panel = MyPanel(self)


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        mygrid = grid.Grid(self)
        mygrid.CreateGrid(26, 9)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(mygrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(parent=None, title="Grid In WxPython")
        self.frame.Show()
        return True


app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

I's there a documented way or other known workaround example to set a Private Font to the Title?

**EDIT:**

Working result here from @Rob's solution :

Sample: https://web.archive.org/web/20221202192613/https://paste.c-net.org/HondoPrairie

```
try:
    gFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
except:
    gFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
gDataDir = os.path.join(gFileDir, "myfonts")

print("gDataDir: ", gDataDir)

filename = os.path.join(gDataDir, "YouthTouchDemoRegular-4VwY.ttf")
wx.Font.AddPrivateFont(filename)

print("filename: ", filename)

self.label_font = self.GetFont()
self.label_font.SetPointSize(18)
self.label_font.SetFamily(wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT)
self.label_font.SetStyle(wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL)
self.label_font.SetWeight(wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)
self.label_font.SetUnderlined(False)
self.label_font.SetFaceName("Youth Touch DEMO")
self.label_font.SetEncoding(wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT)
self.SetFont(self.label_font)
```

Comment: Note to change sample_one.py TitleBar background color, the reference is the `def OnPaint(self, event):` method under: 
`# Use the GCDC to draw the text.         brush = wx.WHITE`
Hex code change :
`brush = wx.Colour("#fec54c")`
RGB change: 
`brush = wx.Colour(44, 134, 179))`

Comment: Title Font Increase Note (still for the `sample_one.py` sample script): Need to change this line from: `tposx, tposy = ((width / 2) - (textWidth / 2), (height / 3) - (textHeight / 3))`  to: `tposx, tposy = ((width / 2) - (textWidth / 2), (height / 1) - (textHeight / 1))` in order for the Title to display it's bottom in full (else it displays with bottom truncated). For example with `self.label_font.SetPointSize(21)` and up as font size.

Comment: Title Text Full Display With Increased font: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74668766/10789707

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting those errors is that the title for a frame is just a string.

To be able to modify the font in the title you will have to create a title bar class based off of `wx.Control` like they did in the sample.
The created title bar will house the label and you will be able to set its font.

When you are ready to set the font run `AddPrivateFont` for it and then  you should be able to reference it by `faceName`.

Also, the `faceName` you have above is not correct compared to the ttf in https://paste.c-net.org/FellasDerby . The `faceName` should be `"Youth Touch DEMO"`

From the docs modified with your font name/file:

```
filename = os.path.join(gDataDir, "YouthTouchDemoRegular-4VwY.ttf")
wx.Font.AddPrivateFont(filename)

st2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'SAMPLETEXT', (15, 42))

f = wx.Font(pointSize=12,
    family=wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
    style=wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
    weight=wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL,
    underline=False,
    faceName="Youth Touch DEMO",
    encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT)

st2.SetFont(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the headup. I've tested the sample with https://pastecode.io/s/b4po5bvg lines 66-77 and 97-99 (I also tesed 79-87, and 89-95) But it's still displaying the default font. Here's my full sample folder: https://paste.c-net.org/FellasDerby Any reason you can spot why it's not working? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, downloaded your sample and was able to see the font in the title bar with those changes.

Comment: Ok, it's working (please ignor my previous comment if it showed up). The working code: https://web.archive.org/web/20221202190925/https://pastecode.io/s/jqscnr79  The final cause of the title not showing up was the wrong `faceName`  I used in the `SetFaceName()` method. I used the one on the right instead of on the left from header here: https://web.archive.org/web/20221202191749/https://i.imgur.com/TiZ5BZi.png Many thanks again! Be well!