# How to make Titlebar height fit new Title Font size increase in WxPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, height, wxwidgets

I've increased the custon `AddPrivateFont` pointsize to

```
self.label_font.SetPointSize(27)
```

of the Title bar of the `sample_one.py` script from this shared project:

https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20add%20a%20menu%20bar%20in%20the%20title%20bar%20%28Phoenix%29

From the script of my previous question here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20221202192613/https://paste.c-net.org/HondoPrairie

[AddPrivateFont to App Title / Title bar in WxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74651265/10789707)

My problem is I can't figure out how to make the Title bar's height larger so the Title text displays its top part correctly. Currently the top of the Title text is truncated.

I tried adjusting the `height` and `textHeight` values from this statement:

```
        textWidth, textHeight = gcdc.GetTextExtent(self.label)
        tposx, tposy = ((width / 2) - (textWidth / 2), (height / 1) - (textHeight / 1))
```

from previous ones (in the `sample_one.py` script):

```
        textWidth, textHeight = gcdc.GetTextExtent(self.label)
        tposx, tposy = ((width / 2) - (textWidth / 2), (height / 3) - (textHeight / 3))
```

Because it truncated the bottom (now the bottom shows up correctly but not the top of the Title text).

There is also this method I'm not sure how to handle:

```
    def DoGetBestSize(self):
        """
        ...
        """

        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())

        textWidth, textHeight = dc.GetTextExtent(self.label)
        spacing = 10
        totalWidth = textWidth + (spacing)
        totalHeight = textHeight + (spacing)

        best = wx.Size(totalWidth, totalHeight)
        self.CacheBestSize(best)

        return best
```

I tried tweaking it and printing results but to no avail.

Here's a preview of the Truncated Title text:

[image: Truncated Text Title Bar Title WxPython]

What would be the correct approach to finding out what controls the height of the title bar object to fix the truncated title text?

Comment: You appear to be hacking away at `MyTitleBar` have you tried adjusting its container `MyTitleBarPnl` which appears to have a fixed height at 24 pixels?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was controlled by both the `MyTitleBarPnl` and `MyFrame` classes. Got it laid out in 3 steps below. Thanks Again. Be well!

Comment: Added 4th step for the Status bar. Now It's done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rolf of Saxony headsup I figured it out!

It took the following 3 steps:

**1st Step:**

**Top Title Text Display from:**

```
class MyTitleBarPnl(wx.Panel):
    def CreateCtrls(self):
        self.titleBar.SetSize((w, 54))

    def OnResize(self, event):
        self.titleBar.SetSize((w, 54))
```

[image: Top Title Text Display]

**2nd Step:**

**Vertical Spacing Below Title Text Without Text Display:**

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def CreateCtrls(self):
        self.titleBarPnl = MyTitleBarPnl(self, -1, (w, 54))

    def OnResize(self, event):
        self.titleBarPnl.SetSize((w, 24))
```

[image: Vertical Spacing Below Title Text Without Text Display]

**3rd Step:**

**Vertical Spacing Below Title Text WithText Display:**

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def CreateCtrls(self):
        self.titleBarPnl = MyTitleBarPnl(self, -1, (w, 54))

    def OnResize(self, event):
        self.titleBarPnl.SetSize((w, 54))
```

[image: Vertical Spacing Below Title Text With Text Display]

**EDIT:**

**4th Step:**

**Status Bar Display:**

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def CreateCtrls(self):
        self.titleBarPnl = MyTitleBarPnl(self, -1, (w, 54))

    def OnResize(self, event):
        self.titleBarPnl.SetSize((w, 54))
        self.mainPnl.SetSize((w, h - 55))  # 25
```

[image: Status Bar Display]